# How to solve Windows Defender Blocking app?

Tags: wpf, windows-10, windows-defender

Hi I wrote a WPF Programm and want to share it. But on other PC's the Microsoft Defender Always blocks this app. How can I stop that problem like every other app?

Comment: Does it pass virustotal?

Comment: Yes you can click view more and install it anyway but its annoying and I want it like every other app

Answer (score 0):

1. Start > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Turn Off. Or-
2. You can add exception for your program. Here the documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26